# ajax prepared statement doesn't update how I like it to

Tags: php, ajax, prepared-statement

I have this piece of PHP code, which is triggered by pressing a button and by an ajax call, here is the ajax call first of all:

```
function rotateObject(e)
{
    //e is handler which contains info about the item clicked. From that we can obtain the image id.
    //since the id are of the form img_123(some number), we need to extract only the number.
    var img_id = e.id.split("_")[1];
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("item").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","database/update_settings_rotate.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("item_id="+encodeURIComponent(img_id));
}
```

this then runs this code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if(isset($_POST['item_id'])){

    $item_number = $_POST['item_id'];

        require('../includes/db_connect.php');

    /* Register a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET rotation = (rotation + 1) % 4 WHERE ref_id = ?')) {

            /* Bind parametres */
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_number);

            /* Execute the query */
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($rotation);

            $stmt->fetch();

            /* Close statement */
            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            /* Something went wrong */
            echo 'Something went terribly wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
        }

}
```

everything runs fine by now but when the button is clicked on, only the database get updated, I then need to make something to update the webpage when the button is clicked, in which case I tried this instead of the code above:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        if(isset($_POST['item_id'])){

        $item_number = $_POST['item_id'];

            require('../includes/db_connect.php');

        /* Register a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET rotation = (rotation + 1) % 4 WHERE ref_id = ?')) {

                /* Bind parametres */
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_number);

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($rotation);

                $stmt->fetch();

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terribly wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
            }

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT x, y, z, src, rotation, link, div_id FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE house_room1.ref_id = ?')) {

                $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_number);

                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $z, $src, $rotation, $link, $div_id);
                while($stmt->fetch()) {
                    if ($link != "") { 
                        echo '<a href="' . $link . '"> ';
                    }
                    if ($div_id != "") { 
                        echo '<a href="#" onClick="' . $div_id . '"> '; 
                    }
                    echo '<img src="' . $src . $rotation .'.png" class="item' . $item_number . '" style="position:absolute; left:' . $x . 'px; top:' . $y . 'px; z-index:'. $z . ';">'; if ($x != 0) { echo'</a>'; }
                }
             else {
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
```

But nothing good came out of that since neither the database or the webpage get updated automatically now. uhm, something might have gone wrong after the `SELECT` query was added but I can't see what should mess it all up. Any ideas, advice or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first example of server-side code I'm not seeing where you output anything on a successful update of the data, so naturally there wouldn't be any change to the UI if there's no output to display.  In the second example it looks like there's some output (a couple of links and an image), are those being returned by the server?

Comment: @David I'm not quite sure. As it is now, nothing happens when the button is pressed, neither the `UPDATE` statement nor `SELECT`. I can't see any differences at all

Comment: Well, "nothing happens" may be a misleading statement. Is the database update performed? When debugging in your browser, what is the response from the server? Again, in the first example I don't see where the code creates a response, so of course there would be no observable change in the UI. The webpage isn't going to change automatically, you have to write code to make it happen. In the second example it looks like there should be some output, so you need to determine where specifically the logic is failing, such as by examining the AJAX response or PHP logs.

Comment: @David console says this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null rotate-object_ajax.js:18
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange" I don't know if it has anything to do with it

Comment: Yes, that's very important.  It means that `document.getElementById("item")` doesn't find any element in your markup, so it can't display anything to that element.  Essentially, your markup doesn't have an element with an id of `item`.  So you'll either need to create one or change that code to output to an element that exists.

Comment: @David oh yeah I see, I changed it to something that makes sense, now the `SELECT` works but do you think it is possible to merge to `UPDATE` with the `SELECT` statement above? Because it gets mixed really bad right now uhm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49355/discussion-between-owwyess-and-david)